# Umbraco 7 Custom Controllers not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have two umbraco sites, one on version 7.1.8 the other on 7.2.4. The site with 7.1.8 has several controllers all of which inherit from PluginController. Other than inheriting from PluginController there have been NO modifications to the models i.e. inheriting from Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel or in the view. It simply works just like normal asp.net MVC. The controllers have no reason to talk to Umbraco.

My second site however doesn't seem to want to work in the same way. Error messages insisting I used Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel etc.

Is there any way to tell Umbraco leave my controllers alone like in the first site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to get the runtime error suggesting to use `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel`:

1) by passing a custom model which does not inherit `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel` into a view inheriting from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage`

2) by passing a custom model which does not inherit `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel` into a view, **which layout expects the model to be of type** `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel`

Since your views do not inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage`, its got to be the second case, so check your layout. E.g. set `Layout = null` in your views explicitely and see if the error is gone.

Refer to *Returning a view with a custom model* section [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers) for more details and possible workarounds.

PS. Note that layout can be set implicitely via _ViewStart.cshtml located in the Views folder.